# Django : How to import a python module such as pytube into a static template/webpage?

Tags: python, django, web

I am very new to Django. Recently I was developing a site just for getting aquainted with the framework and I came to a point where I needed to import a python module such as request,pytube etc into a static webpage so that i can use their functions . So two questions arose - 
1. Is it possible to have python code embedded in static content.
2. How can I import a python module into a static webpage.

Comment: what do you mean with static content / static webpage, can you provide an example?

Comment: No. You can't just run arbitrary functions in an html page (I think what you mean by static web page). You will need to use a django view to run the function and render the result in an html template

Comment: you can render a "static" html page through a view (or possible a direct_to_template generic view), which allows you to add logic like template filters (which can be implemented to use your library).

Answer (score 3):

Python code cannot be executed by the browser within the page. If you wish to execute code within the browser you will need to use JavaScript, which would be a completely different process. If you wish to manipulate values from a webpage using Django and other Python libraries, you will need to set up a form, take the input, wash it through a views.py file with the classes or functions you need, and then return those values as context variables that are rendered through template tags in your static page upon load.

If you are new to Django, I would *highly* recommend looking through the Django Project's main [tutorial, found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: I was trying to do the following. I have a textbox in my template where the user enters a link. I needed to extract the link from the textbox and pass it to a python module defined in the templatetags folder.  {% get_videolist THE_TEXTBOX_VAR as videos %}
     {% for video in videos%}
 <li>{{video}}</li>
    {% endfor %} where get_videolist is a module that i loaded into the template page and which returns a list.